# How to remove folding in R code in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, folding

Very basic question but one that I am struggling with and thus can use some guidance...

I am working in Rstudio and modifying an existing script. It is full of foldable regions and they are really poorly organized. I'd like to delete all the folding and start again, but I cannot find any information on how to actually remove the folding (arrow below) from the code. Help is really appreciated.

[image]

I tried Edit > Folding > Collapse, but of course that just folds the code and does not get rid of the fold breaks.

Comment: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE says that `Shift+Alt+O` should expand all, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: looking to remove the fold breaks, not expand them

Comment: You cannot remove them as they are auto generated from language elements (such as `function` declaration, `if` or `for` statement or specially formatted comments (ending with `----` or `====`)

Comment: thank you Billy34, that makes sense now that I'm looking into the code more.

Comment: @Billy34 But according to https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE "You can also fold an arbitrary selection of code by using Edit -> Folding -> Collapse (Alt-L)." So those arbitrary sections aren't auto generated. But it's unclear where that information is stored or how your remove them.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't aware of it :-) It must be stored somewhere in `.Rproj.user` subfolder. But if you expand a section collapsed that way, the fold disappear. There is no triangle like icon in the gutter. It's a one time temporary fold